# JSDom does not render XHR requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to make JSDOM behave like a browser and return rendered html. I'm having a problem with a website that uses XHR. Is there any incompatibility? JSDOM doesn't work with XHR?? I tried several things but none worked.

I started with this basic code that didn't work:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

let options ='{ resources: "usable" , runScripts: "dangerously" }';

JSDOM.fromURL("https://yog9.github.io/SnapShot/#/SnapScout/mountain", options).then(dom => {
  console.log(dom.serialize());
});
```

Then I tried this code which rendered more things but still didn't get the items required by XHR

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

var dom = JSDOM.fromURL("https://yog9.github.io/SnapShot/#/SnapScout/mountain", 
{ runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable"}).then( dom => {
    
    const { window } = dom
    const { document } = window
    
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        title = document.querySelector('title').textContent
        //console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML)
        console.log(dom.serialize());
       //window.close()
      });


})
```

PS: Although it is the most recommended solution, the headless browser (puppeteer) is not an option because it is too slow for what I need.

Comment: Out-of-the-box, JSDOM does not fully support making XHR requests. This is because it is focused on simulating a DOM environment and not a full browser with all networking capabilities.

Comment: What data are you trying to get exactly? Please describe the underlying goal rather than focusing entirely on your attempted solution.

Comment: I want the rendered html of the page sent in the example with everything that is loaded on it